# Angular dynamic validation based on other data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have an ng-repeat that spits out data and inputs that can be made to fix the data. If a portion of each repeat is of a certain value, I need to restrict the ways the input can be used.

So, for instance, there is a list of equipment, and for service type 1511, the maximum quantity is 1. They need to fix it, and I want to ensure that they don't type in a number that's invalid that will cause another issue to arise.

How can this be done?

edit: Updated jsfiddle and below code to be pared down to just the repeated bits.

Example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AKarstaedt/vfuj8sjt/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TaskActivityCtrl" class="container-fluid">
  <form novalidate name="taskActivityForm">
    <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="service in bill.services">
      <div data-ng-repeat="serviceCharge in service.serviceCharges">
        <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="col-md-3">Service Code</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Attribute</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Billed/Invoiced Value</th>
                <th class="col-md-5">Updated Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">{{ service.serviceCode }}
                </td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td class="existQuantity">{{ serviceCharge.quantity }}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="New quantity" data-ng-model="serviceCharge.newQuantity" min="0">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('TaskActivityCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.bill = {
          "services": [{
            "billableIndicator": true,
            "serviceCode": "1511",
            "serviceCharges": [{
              "equipment": {
                "equipmentInitial": "TTEX",
                "equipmentNumber": "988172"
              },
              "quantity": 2,
              "rate": 5000,
              "amount": 10000,
              "unitTypeCode": "PC",
              "billableIndicator": true,
              "billableDisplay": "Y",
              "suspendIndicator": false
            }, {
              "equipment": {
                "equipmentInitial": "TTEX",
                "equipmentNumber": "90099"
              },
              "quantity": 1,
              "rate": 7888,
              "amount": 7888,
              "unitTypeCode": "PC",
              "billableIndicator": true,
              "billableDisplay": "Y",
              "suspendIndicator": false
            }]
          }, {
            "billableIndicator": true,
            "serviceCode": "1530",
            "serviceCharges": [{
              "equipment": {
                "equipmentInitial": "TTEX",
                "equipmentNumber": "988172"
              },
              "quantity": 25,
              "rate": 200,
              "amount": 5000,
              "unitTypeCode": "PM",
              "billableIndicator": true,
              "billableDisplay": "Y",
              "suspendIndicator": false
            }]
      }],
    }
  });
```

Comment: Controller code please?

Comment: I would suggest isolating a specific issue in a simple piece of code so that it's more easily readable.  Too much irrelevant code and markup here and in the fiddle

Comment: I updated the code and fiddle to make it a bit more readable. Added the controller (which is just the JSON assigned to a scope variable).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple positive integer validation on your code. I have made slight changes to html and js. But you need to modify it to suit your needs.

The idea is that user will eventually press some kind of submit button, and this button is attached to an ng-click event. In this ng-click event handler, you will perform the validation before submitting changes.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7nnn7e8u/1/)

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TaskActivityCtrl" class="container-fluid">
  <form novalidate name="taskActivityForm">
    <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="service in bill.services">
      <div data-ng-repeat="serviceCharge in service.serviceCharges">
        <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="col-md-3">Code</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Attribute</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Value</th>
                <th class="col-md-5">Updated Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">{{ service.serviceCode }}
                </td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td class="existQuantity">{{ serviceCharge.quantity }}</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="New quantity" data-ng-model="serviceCharge.newQuantity" min="0">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="submitData()">
    Submit Changes
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('TaskActivityCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.bill = {
                    "services": [{
                      "billableIndicator": true,
                      "serviceCode": "1511",
                      "serviceCharges": [{
                        "equipment": {
                          "equipmentInitial": "TTEX",
                          "equipmentNumber": "988172"
                        },
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "rate": 5000,
                        "amount": 10000,
                        "unitTypeCode": "PC",
                        "billableIndicator": true,
                        "billableDisplay": "Y",
                        "suspendIndicator": false
                      }, {
                        "equipment": {
                          "equipmentInitial": "TTEX",
                          "equipmentNumber": "90099"
                        },
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "rate": 7888,
                        "amount": 7888,
                        "unitTypeCode": "PC",
                        "billableIndicator": true,
                        "billableDisplay": "Y",
                        "suspendIndicator": false
                      }]
                    }, {
                      "billableIndicator": true,
                      "serviceCode": "1530",
                      "serviceCharges": [{
                        "equipment": {
                          "equipmentInitial": "TTEX",
                          "equipmentNumber": "988172"
                        },
                        "quantity": 25,
                        "rate": 200,
                        "amount": 5000,
                        "unitTypeCode": "PM",
                        "billableIndicator": true,
                        "billableDisplay": "Y",
                        "suspendIndicator": false
                      }]
                    }],
                  }

        $scope.submitData = function(){
        var isValid = true;
        for(var i in $scope.bill.services){   
        var service = $scope.bill.services[i];      
        for(var j in service.serviceCharges){
            var serviceCharge = service.serviceCharges[j];

          //check that newQuantity is a positive integer
          //if is positive integer
          alert(parseInt(serviceCharge.newQuantity) + " vs " + serviceCharge.newQuantity);
          if(parseInt(serviceCharge.newQuantity) == serviceCharge.newQuantity && 
              serviceCharge.newQuantity >= 0){
            //do nothing?
          } else {
            isValid = false;
            break;
          }
        }
        if(!isValid) break;
      }

      isValid? alert("values validated") : alert("validation failed");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the requirements are such that it needs to be an in-field validation. I'm thinking a directive may need to be created to create a custom validation.

Comment: @AndrewSquared oh.. yes in that case you need to use a directive. Ideally each of your service charge block will be a directive (a reusable component). In your directive, use $watch to listen for changes. validate as changes are passed through